# Can images be called using ZPL Programming based on another called input

Tags: zpl

I am fairly new to ZPL programming, I am looking to print a label with several images using a Zebra printer. I am creating a template, which cannot change, however, the images that I want in the template do change based on what is printed. Is is possible to print different images based on what is pulled into the template?

I know the the ZPL code can pull text information from a defined data field, but is is possible to pull an image for a defined data field in the ZPL code?

^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4~SD30^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW927
^LL927
^LS0
^FT10,50^A0N,60,50^FH^FDxxxxx.entity.ehs_warning^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Here the ehs_warning is a set of attachments that contain multiple files of ehs warning images. Would ZPL be able to pull this information and display the image.

Comment: You can store image files in the printer then use them in a template. However it is not clear which warning images are to be printed based on a "template which cannot change". Do you mean there will be some data in the template that *will* change and based on that data one or another image should be printed?

Comment: Correct, I guess to clarify I meant to say that the information is pulled from a software system and that information is categorized as a variable, so say, entity.ph. but for entity.ehs_warnings there are multiple ones that I need (say 6) but there could be multiple combinations for each label or none at all. It just depends what I have listed in the entity.ehs_warning.